# Code block that executes after all other ContinueWith blocks of code execution are complete

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task

I am looking for a mechanism that enables me to specify a block of code that executes after all other `continueWith` blocks of code have finished execution. The behaviour I am looking for, is to some extent similar to `finally` block execution in `try-catch-finally`.

For example, in an application, I want to display a waitImage before I start the task and want to make the waitImage invisible when execution of all other continuewith blocks are complete.

Mainly I deal with `OnlyOnFaulted` and `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` continueWith blocks and intend to have the code of making the waitimage invisible in a block of code that executes under any condition(OnlyOnFaulted/OnlyOnRanToCompletion/Or any other) and executes only after execution of all other ContinueWith blocks related to the task is complete.

Please help.

Regards,
Anirban

Comment: Is there a problem with using taskfactory.continuewhenall

Comment: I have never used it. But documentation suggests "Creates a continuation task that starts when a set of specified tasks has completed." What I am looking for, is to find a method/mechanism that would execute when all continueWith blocks reletad to a particular task is complete. Are you suggesting to pass the array of single task in the task array of taskfactory.continuewhenall ??

Comment: Yes.  Build up an array of tasks execute them and then add a continue when all

Comment: I guess there has been some misunderstanding. As I specified in the question and also in the last comment, I am looking for a solution where a block of code would execute when all continuewith blocks of code related to A PARTICULAR TASK is complete. And For each Task I initiate, That block would have different code statements depending upon the task. From the documentation of taskfactory.continuewhenall, it seems that this method is actually meant to be used in a situation where I want to execute a block of code when a number of tasks are complete.

Comment: So that is why I am wondering whether using  taskfactory.continuewhenall is the best option in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

To wait on all of the children of a Task you must pass `TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent` in your call to continue with.  The call wait on the parent.  It can be seen in this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).